# script block in partialview prevents from fire onclick event on IE9

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a simple partial view with a script block:

```
<input type="button" onclick="alert('clicked');" value="click me" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">alert("bla");</script>
```

when i click on the button the onclick event not fires. 
when i remove the script block it works.
it only happens on IE9 (chrome and firefox are OK).
any ides? :\
thanks!

Comment: probably not the problem, but you don't need the language="javascript"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure , but move the  above the  tag , and give it a try !!